# Obtener datos de un campo de una tabla y comparar con otro para ver si existe, en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Lo que deseo hacer es, traer todos los datos registrados del campo **'fecha'** de mi tabla **'registros'**, y ver si entre esos datos que están en esa tabla, existe uno ya registrado.

El código que tengo es este a continuación.

Aquí filtro los registros del usuario por su 'dni', y logro que la condición que está mas abajo se aplique al ultimo registro. Lo que trato de hacer es que, en vez de que traiga el ultimo registro, me traiga todos los datos registrados en el campo **'fecha'**, y compararlo con la fecha actual que capturo por medio de Carbon, para ver si hay alguno existente en los registros del campo **'fecha'**.

```
$registro = Registro::latest('id')->where('dni', $dni)->first();

 $fecha = Carbon::now();
 $fecha_hoy = $fecha -> format('Y-m-d');

 $FechaRegistrada = $registro -> fecha;

 if ($FechaRegistrada == $fecha_hoy){
                return redirect('/asistencia#down')->with('alert-danger', '¡ El dato ya existe !');
            }
            else {

                  //Código si no se cumple la condición

          }
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Con esta consulta obtienes la cantidad de registros donde el atributo `dni` sea igual al que tienes en la variable `$dni` y la fecha del atributo `fecha` sea igual a la fecha de hoy. Si ningún registro coincide, te devolverá `0` (cero).

```php
$count = Registro::where('dni', $dni)
    ->whereDate('fecha', Carbon::now())
    ->count();
```

Luego pones la condición, si `$count` vale `0`, devolverá `false`, si vale más de cero, devolverá `true`.

```php
if($count)
    // El dato ya existe
else
    // no existe
```

Comment: No es necesario usar la clase `Carbon` con hacer uso de `now()` obtienes una instancia de la misma

Comment: @Aprendiz claro, puedes usar el helper, pero detrás de bambalinas es una instancia de Carbon https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-now.

Answer (score 1):

A como entiendo tu pregunta lo que deseas es obtener al final el conteo de todos los registros cuya fecha coincide con la de hoy en un contador; entonces dado eso deberías

- Eliminar el método first y usar en su lugar `get` para obtener todos los registros
- Crear un contador que este al inicio en 0
- Recorrer con un `foreach` la colección y evaluar por dentro con el uso de un condicional aquellos registros que en la columna fecha sea igual a la de hoy
- No uses la clase Carbon, con hacer uso de `now()` obtienes una instancia de la misma
- Para formatear la fecha de Carbon por que asumo que en tu columna solo guardas año, mes y día usa mejor el método `toDateString()`

**Propuesta de código**

```
$registros = Registro::latest('id')->where('dni', $dni)->get();
$fecha     = now()->toDateString();
$contador  = 0;

foreach($registros as $registro) 
{
    if ($registro->fecha === $fecha) 
    {
        $contador++;
        //resto de las acciones
    } else {
        //acciones si no coinciden las fechas
    }
}

return $contador;//retornas por fuera del foreach y dentro del método a $contador
```

O como ya te propusieron en la otra respuesta, solo que pasando al método `whereDate()` la fecha formateada que obtuvimos de la instancia de Carbon

```
$fecha     = now()->toDateString();
$registros = Registro::where('dni', $dni)
                    ->whereDate('fecha', $fecha)
                    ->count();
```

> Para este último caso vamos a obtener solo un número entero mayor o igual a 0 por lo que el método de ordenamiento descendente que brinda `latest()` no es necesario por eso lo quité